# How to write "if not class" jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to do something with var p:

```
var p = $("li:last");
```

But I don't want to do anything if there is a certain Class appended. I tried :not like this:

```
var p = $("li:last:not(.Class)");
```

This doesn't work. How can I exclude .Class in my var?

Comment: Just to clarify The `:not` selector and `.not` is supposed to behave the same. Meaning, `var p = $("li:last").not(".Class");` and `var p = $('li:last:not(.Class)')` Should work the same way. >> See your code working http://jsfiddle.net/skram/76NNp/ <<

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
var p = $("li:last").not(".Class");
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: `:not(.Class)` should do the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: @Vega since OP is also using `:last`, there may be some confusion in the engine as to which is applied first.

Comment: @Vega, you're right, and actually it appears to work fine for me when I try it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rhta/2/ (change the class name and it works, leave it as `Class` and it doesn't do anything).

Comment: @mblase75 There shouldn't be any confusion when using it properly. See demo http://jsfiddle.net/skram/76NNp/

Answer (score 15):

Actually `:not` does work as a selector.

If you want to select the last element that doesn't have the class, use this

```
var p = $("li:not(.Class):last");
```

This selects first the `li`s that don't have that class, and *then* the last of them. [See it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/5rhta/1/).

To make it perfectly clear, these are equivalent:

```
var p = $("li:not(.Class):last");
var p = $("li").not(".Class").last();
```

And, also, these are equivalent:

```
var p = $("li:last:not(.Class)");
var p = $("li").last().not(".Class");
```

Comment: OP seems to want to select the last element ONLY IF it's not `.Class`, and if it is, select nothing. At least that's how I read it.

Comment: I added some further explanation to make what's happening in the code a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and elaborating (+1) but Im going with the answer provided by bhamlin, he was first, its simple and it worked like a charm

Comment: @Youss Just to clarify The `:not` selector and `.not` is supposed to behave the same. Meaning, `var p = $("li:last").not(".Class");` and `var p = $('li:last:not(.Class)')` Should work the same way. >> See your code working http://jsfiddle.net/skram/76NNp/ <<

Answer (score 2):

```
var p = $("li:last");
if (!p.hasClass('Class')){
//some stuff
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. Particularly useful as the element had more than one class.